# code version of #if debug

Tags: c#

Is there a code version of

```
#if DEBUG
```

I have tried `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached` but this is only true if you are stepping through the code rather than if you are not in release mode

EDIT:

I have some centralised code that I am running across multiple mvc projects which I link to the project, but as they are linked items they can't be bundled whilst I am developing as the files aren't copied until I publish the site so I was wanting to check if in debug mode so I could use a virtual directory of the files I have created on the dev server

```
@Html.Partial(IsDebug ? virtualDirectory : normalPartial)
```

instead of having to do

```
#if DEBUG
    @Html.Partial(virtualDirectory)
#else
    @Html.Partial(normalPartial)
#endif
```

Comment: What do you mean "code version"? `DEBUG` is something that characterizes the *build*, not the runtime situation.

Comment: Pete: It doesn't matter. `#if DEBUG` is still how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "code version" could be

```
#if DEBUG
  bool DebugMode = true;
#else
  bool DebugMode = false;
#endif
```

Comment: Looks like this is the best solution for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Conditional`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) attribute:

```
class Class1 
{
   [Conditional("DEBUG")]
   public static void M() {
      Console.WriteLine("Executed Class1.M");
   }
}
```

It can be used only on whole methods.